# Pydantic: How do I call a superclass method inside a subclass validator?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to validate a subclass using a superclass method, but I am doing something fundamentally wrong and cannot figure out.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator, root_validator

class Name(BaseModel):
  name: str

  def name_has_two_parts(self):
    return len(self.name.split())==2

class FirstLast(Name):
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    @classmethod
    def check_parts(cls, values):
        #assert len(values["name"].split())==2  # <-- this works fine
        assert super().name_has_two_parts(), f'Some message here'  # <-- this does NOT work
        return values

first_last = FirstLast(name="First Last")
```

With this I get the following error:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for FirstLast
__root__
  name_has_two_parts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' (type=type_error)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the following:

#### Calling an instance method from a class method

Since `check_parts` is a (root) validator, it is a **class method**. (This is also hinted by the fact that the first parameter is called `cls`.) This is correct because that is how Pydantic validators work. They are called *before* a model instance is fully initialized.

However, your `name_has_two_parts` method is an **instance method** of the `Name` class and by inheritance also of the `FirstLast` class. (Hinted again by the first argument being called `self`.) This is fine in and of itself, since I assume you want to use it as such with an instance of `Name`, as in something like this:

```py
instance = Name(name="foo bar")
print(instance.name_has_two_parts())  # output: `True`
```

But you cannot then call it from the class, i.e. this does not work:

```py
Name.name_has_two_parts()  # TypeError: Name.name_has_two_parts() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

There is no `self` to provide because no instance is present in that call.

Yet this is exactly what you do in this class method:

```py
...
    def check_parts(cls, values):
        assert super().name_has_two_parts()
```

That `super` call inside a class method is equivalent to `super(FirstLast, cls).name_has_two_parts()`, which in turn results in the `name_has_two_parts` method being called on the `Name` class as I did above.

One possible solution would be to factor out that logic for checking the number of parts into its own *static* method (as it doesn't rely on any class or instance attributes) and then call it separately in both your instance method and the validator:

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class Name(BaseModel):
    name: str

    @staticmethod
    def has_two_parts(string: str) -> bool:
        return len(string.split()) == 2

    def name_has_two_parts(self) -> bool:
        return self.has_two_parts(self.name)


class FirstLast(Name):
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def check_parts(cls, values: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        assert cls.has_two_parts(values["name"]), "Some message here"
        return values


if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_last = FirstLast(name="First Last")
    assert first_last.name_has_two_parts()
    # wrong = FirstLast(name="First Last Third")  # causes a `ValidationError`
```

---

As a side note, the `@classmethod` decorator is not needed in conjunction with the `@root_validator` (or a regular `@validator`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Daniil Fajnberg, this works great :) Also thank you for the beautiful explanation, and the side note!